# The Analytic/Synthetic Distinction in false mathematical propositions

Tags: philosophy-of-science, analytic-synthetic-divide

Are all mathematical propositions a priori analytic? 
The most common example used is 2+2=4. The truth lies in the meaning of the parts of the proposition, and is therefore a priori analytic.

But when the proposition is: 2+2=5 is it still an a priori analytic proposition?

Comment: It's pretty easy to turn false statement into a true one, just negate it. If the (true) negation is analytic then presumably so is the original. Whether  2+2=/=5 is analytic depends on one's philosophy of mathematics, Kant thought it was synthetic, Frege thought it was analytic, and Quine thought the distinction itself doesn't make sense because we can't really tell when the "truth lies in the meaning" and when it does not, "meaning" is an obscure concept.

Comment: it's not clear to me that 2+2=4 is an analytic proposition. it's not like "all bachelors are unmarried men."

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic–synthetic_distinction Kant: 7+5=12 is synthetic a priori. not analytic. dunno if that's right, it is wikipedia,  but it makes sense: the meaning of 12 is not already included in the other meanings.

Comment: sorry, SE does not like dashes in URLs. Google "Analytic-synthetic distinction".

Comment: "The truth lies in the meaning of the parts of the proposition, and is therefore a priori analytic." that's compositionality, not analyticity.  the latter means that the meaning of the one is already included in the meaning of the other. not the case for e.g. 2+2=4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we stay with the definition of [Analytic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic/) according to which :

> “Analytic” sentences are those whose truth seems to be knowable by knowing the meanings of the constituent words alone, unlike the more usual “synthetic” ones whose truth is knowable by both knowing the meaning of the words and something about the world,

we have that from : **2+2=5** and the other axioms for arithmetic, by purely logical transformations, we can derive : **¬(2+2=4)**, i.e. the negation of an analytical sentences.

*If* - according to the above definition - we can know the truth-value of **2+2=4** without referring to "information" about the world, this holds also for **2+2=5**.

Comment: you cannot derive : ¬(2+2=4) from  2+2=5 by purely logical means. such a derivation would depend on substantial exra-logical assumptions, like the meanings of "2", etc.

Comment: This definition seems out of place here since the sentence is mathematical. If one subscribes to a version of Kantian "synthetic a priori" one can have synthetic without any "truths about the world". The question really is if the axioms of arithmetic are analytic or synthetic, and this definition is not particularly illuminating on that. I think the best we can say is that it is analytic-in-Peano-arithmetic, which simply means deducible in it, but that has little to do with "knowing the meanings".

Comment: @mobileink: Mauro made it very clear by saying "and the other axioms for arithmetic". There are absolutely no extra-logical assumptions. It is a purely symbolic matter. For a concrete example of such an axiom system, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations, and define "2" as "1+1" and "4" as "1+1+1+1" and "5" as "1+1+1+1+1", and play the PA proof game.

Comment: @user21820: "other axioms of arithmetic" may be clear to you and me but let's not assume the same is true for everybody. Also, those axioms are already exra-logical.

Comment: @mobileink: I have no idea what you mean by "extra-logical". Do you know basic first-order logic? **Any** logical system comes with a set of axioms. Obviously, you need a meta-system to **define** a logical system, but no logician calls the axioms themselves "extra-logical". Instead, since we can write a proof of "¬ 2+2 = 5" completely within a system axiomatizing arithmetic (an example of which I have already linked for those who don't know any), every logician considers that proof to be **not** meta-logical.

Comment: @user21820: 1) symbols that are not logical are extra-logical; it's a common term.  /\ (logical AND) is a logical symbol; "2" and "+" etc. are extra-logical; their meanings are not dtermined by logic.  this is elementary. 2) it is patently false that all logical systems come with axioms.  e.g. there are no axioms in ituitionistic logic.  that's precisely the point of difference between classic truth-conditional logic and intuitionistic logic. 3. you can write a mathematical proof of "! 2+2=5".  that does not make it a logical proof.

Comment: @user21820: ok, I see your point about the axioms not involving exra-logical stuff. but when you go from meta symbols like a*b to symbols like 2+ 2 you move to extra-logical symbols . no?

Comment: @user21820: can we agree that while   !(2+2=5) is mathematically true it is not logically true?

Comment: @mobileink: None of my comments involved any meta symbols, so I don't know what you're referring to. All you need is that the language has the constant-symbol "1" and function-symbol "+" (which for convenience we write in infix notation, but we could just as well write "+(1,+(1,1))" for "1+1+1". Similarly, when we define "2" as "1+1" we mean a literal symbolic substitution. If you are pedantic you can call "2" a meta-symbol if it is not supported by the language. But you can just as well choose a language that does have the constant-symbol "2" and an axiom "2 = 1+1".

Comment: @mobileink: As for your second comment, there is no such thing as "logically true" in the absolute sense. You **always** need to choose a particular formal system, which usually comprises inference rules. In the case of a first-order formal system, if you only have inference rules for the boolean connectives, then yes you obviously cannot prove a statement that has so-called non-logical symbols. A first-order theory **always** comes with a language specifying which function-symbols and predicate symbols are available. But standard terminology also says "φ is logically true over T" if "T ⊨ φ".

Comment: @user21820: "no such thing as 'logically true' in the absolute sense"?  but "logically true in the relative sense" is an oxymoron, no? "phi is logically true over T if 'T entails phi'".  close but no cookie.  phi is logically true over T *if and only if* T entails phi *under all models*.  Maybe we should continue this in discussion.

Comment: @mobileink: "T ⊨ φ" (entails) means exactly what you said, namely "φ is true in all models of T". **However**, that is hardly near "absolute"! To even speak of models, you need a fairly strong meta-system (see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1808558), which is certainly not an absolute unique choice! Different meta-systems will **disagree** about what are models of $T$! I certainly don't mind continuing in chat; come over to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic! Feel free to write your thoughts there and I'll respond when I come online.

Comment: @mobileink: Another point I was making in my earlier comment was that (even if you **fix** the meta-system) you still need to choose a formal system for your logic. Intuitionistic (first-order) logic for example does not have LEM and therefore has fewer tautologies than classical logic. Even within classical first-order logic, a larger language permits expressing more sentences, and naturally more tautologies. So there is really no absoluteness to truth in logic.

Comment: @Conifold The foundation of analytical knowledge is merely the connection between ideas creating new ideas. The Peano axioms are the simplest example of how the semantic meaning can be exhaustively specified syntactically.

Comment: @Conifold Kurt Gödel (1944)
By the theory of simple types I mean the doctrine which says that the objects of thought ... are divided into types, namely: individuals, properties of individuals, relations between individuals, properties of such relations...

Answer (score 0):

*If* the first proposition (2+2=4) is apriori analytic, then so is the second (2+2=5); the first happens to be true, and the latter false.

This suggests that you're simply asking whether apriori analytic propositions can be *false*, given that most examples show *only* true ones. They can be, a proposition has to be judged to be true or false; so there are true propositions, as well as false propositions; a proposition is not one that is neccessarily true, but a question that is proposed, so the first proposition properly posed is:

> Is 2 added to 2 equal to four?

to which, the answer is true; and

> Is 2 added to 2 equal to five?

to which, the answer is false.